# PhpStorm 7 tooltips positions

Tags: phpstorm

How to show live templates first in tooltips, like in a screenshot? 
[image]

Comment: Wait for next minor version: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115287 . Alternatively, you may disable **automatic** code completion popup and invoke it manually when needed (Ctrl+Space) -- in such case live template will be expanded properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue -- already fixed: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115287

Hopefully it will be in next minor version -- 7.0.1 (should be, as quite a few users got very annoyed by current behaviour).

---

Currently you will have to close code completion popup (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) in order for Live Template to expand properly (or explicitly choose it from the list).

*Alternative approach* (which can be used in mean time): disable **automatic** code completion popup (`Settings | Editor | Code Completion`) and invoke it manually when needed (<kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>) -- in such case live template will be expanded properly as no code completion popup is shown.

And yes, if you already got used to have automatic popup showing up, this workflow may be quite inconvenient. On another hand -- very often such popup shows when I do not want to see it.