# Make PHPStorm autocomplete with live template instead of variable

Tags: phpstorm

I have defined a template with shortcut "c" and want to have it used whenever I press Tab after entering "c". It worked properly in PHPStorm 6, but in PHPStorm 7 this seems to instead expand to the name of a variable starting with c - with template being the second option in the dropdown list. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Is code completion popup is visible at that moment or not? If answer is yes -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/19707214/783119

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhpStorm 7 tooltips positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677124/phpstorm-7-tooltips-positions)